# Friends can't find me after reactivate account

Tags: facebook

I deactivated account in Thursday night, in the next morning, I reactivated account, but when I logged on facebook, the menu Find Friends on header bar is gone, otherwise, I tried posting a status, but my friends didn't see it, and my friend can find my timeline page. The facebook said: 'The page you requested was not found'.

After searching on facebook community. I have to wait for account to work again. But how long I wait?

Comment: Did you resolve this issue?

Comment: Can it be reproduced?